# Poco Thread How Can I Avoid Using Join

Tags: poco-libraries

Trying to use a Poco::Thread to run a task that takes about a minute to complete.

```
Tfile_creater_runnable file_creater_runnable();
file_creater_thread.start(file_creater_runnable);
file_creater_thread.join();
```

It works great as long as I call join, if I don't it throws an exception in _target.run(). But if I call join it will of course wait until the thread completes a minute later.  I'm trying to use a thread because because I want the main thread to be able to continue executing. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something here. Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Comment: It's an access violation.  I figured it out, the runable was going out of scope.